# Wake up the bot on a Hi and should start with same functionality

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-bot-service, adaptive-cards

How to wake up the bot on "Hi"?

Actually I am in a dialog which has a prompt containing an adaptive card. 
I just want that after clicking on that adaptive card it goes directly to the main dialog and begins with the same functionality as when the bot started working.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please, post some code along with your question.

Comment: I posted the code on my new post for the same

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wake up the functionality on hi on clicking on others in product issue(A dialog) its goes to main dailog and show 4 choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59100901/wake-up-the-functionality-on-hi-on-clicking-on-others-in-product-issuea-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

There would be a part of code where you would be checking the reply for adaptive card.

There check if the user has entered "Hi" to the adaptive card. If so, then just End Dialog there, by,

```
stepContext.EndDialogAsync(null, cancellationToken);
```

It would automatically begin from the very start. Hope this helps. Feel free to ask any queries!

Comment: I am trying this  but getting error..i just posted a other question with my code..can you check and helpout. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59100901/wake-up-the-functionality-on-hi-on-clicking-on-others-in-product-issuea-dialog  here is link for reference

Comment: This not helping out

Comment: Plez any can help out with this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59100901/wake-up-the-functionality-on-hi-on-clicking-on-others-in-product-issuea-dialog here is the entire code present